# Bellman Ford vs Dijkstra

Tags: applications

I have some confusions related to the application of Dijkstra and Bellman Ford algorithms.

Can Bellman Ford be used on undirected graph, or it is only for directed ones? I recognize it because most books apply them whenever I encounter a digraph.

Answer (score 0):

See page 128 of [this book.](http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~naveen/courses/CSL630/all.pdf) There's no reason for anyone to retype it.